# Angulars + Rails: ngInclude directive not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, templates, partial-views, angularjs-ng-include

I'm working on a rails + angularjs app.

Here is my file structure:

```
app/
assets/
    javascript/
    templates/
       home.html
       partial.html
```

Inside the home.html.erb file I want to include the partial.html.erb file.

home.html.erb

```
<ng-include src="'partial.html'"></ng-include>
```

I also tried

```
<ng-include src="'<%= asset_path('partial.html') %>'"></ng-include>
```

But still doesn't work... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setup gem "angular-rails-templates"](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates)

It will automaticaly compile your templates into javascript, and make them available to angular. After that you may use ng-include as usual.

```
<ng-include src="'templates/partial.tpl.html'"></ng-include>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to mix server templates and AngularJS' templates. Put your AngularJS templates in your public directory, then put in the `src` attribute the path to this template from the client.

`public/templates/partial.tpl.html` => `<ng-include src="'/templates/partial.tpl.html'></ng-include>"`

Another way to get the template from the client is to compile your templates to a JS file with [html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) for example.